# Connecting two DSL modems via LAN cable to act as repeater

Tags: lan, wireless-access-point, modem, dsl

I have two DSL modems (TD-W8961ND and TD-W8151N). One of them is connected to the telephone line and is acting as a wireless access point. What I want to do is to use my second wireless modem to act as the repeater of the first one.

**I'm aware of the possibility of WDS but** the two wireless modems are more than 100 meters away from each other (no direct sight); So, I was wandering is there anyway that I connect the two modems via LAN cable so as to the second modem could also get internet from the first one and act as a second access point?

Comment: Your title is misleading.  It reads like you want a DSL repeater.  BTW not every "DSL modem" includes a WAP.

Answer (score 0):

Set your primary modem attached to the telephone line as 192.168.1.254 and the secondary modem for wifi as 192.168.1.253. You can change IP configuration as you want. Note that IP's set above is just an example.